# How do inherit list items in Python?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I'm learning Object Orientated Programming in Python and putting together an adventure game.

Each room is a object instance that inherits from a Scene class. In each room I have a list of commands that can be used in that room. The program checks user input against this list to see if the command matches (and then goes on to perform the appropriate function: go to a another room, pick up the key, that sort of thing).

I want the Scene class to contain a list of stock commands for any room (help, inventory, that sort of thing). But when the engine checks for the commands in each particular room it overrides the list of commands in the superclass. How can I change this code so that the items in commands in class Castle(Scene) also contains the items in commands in class Scene(object)?

Sorry if this is a bit basic for you all. There are similar questions on here but I can't really make sense of them in my code. I'm new to OOP.

```
class Scene(object):
    commands = [
        'help',
        'inventory'
        ]

    def action(self, command):
        if command == 'inventory':
            print "You are carrying the following items:"
            # function to display items will go here


class Castle(Scene):
    def enter(self):
        print "You are in a castle"

    commands = [
        'get key',
        'east'
        ] 

    def action(self, command):
        if command == 'get key':
            print "You pick up the key"
            return 'castle'
        elif command == 'east':
            print "You go east"
            return 'village'
        else:
            pass
        return(0)
```

Comment: You have to extend `commands` in `Castle`. Please dont assign value to `commands` class. Just extend it and add new values.`

Comment: It sounds like `commands` should be a map to map command strings to behaviour. However, this is too complicated for what you need.  Remove `commands` and just make `action` do what it needs to do. In addition you need to define what `action` returns and make `Castle.action` call `super().action(command)` first and examine the return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use properties:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     @property
...     def x(self):
...         return [1]
...
>>>
>>> class B(A):
...     @property
...     def x(self):
...         return super(B, self).x + [2]
...
>>> b = B()
>>> b.x
[1, 2]
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. It opens a whole bunch of other issues though.